# show multiple rows of HorizontalListView

Tags: android

I am trying to display multiple [HorizontalListView](http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34) in a linearlayout. However, I can only see the firs HorizontalListView. All stuff after that disappeared. 
The following is the layout.xml`

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/main_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView
                android:id="@+id/saladMenuView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#ddd"
                android:fillViewport="false" />

            <com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView
                android:id="@+id/pizzaMenuView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#ddd"
                android:fillViewport="false" />
    </LinearLayout>`
```

I can always see saladMenuView, but pizzaMenuView never shows up.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Try removing android:fillViewport="false"

Comment: try adding some content to both of them

Comment: I found the reason. It seems the problem is caused by **"android:layout_height="wrap_content"**. If I specify a fixed height like **"android:layout_height="220dp"**, then the next both horizontallistview will showup? Does anyone know why?

Comment: don't know why, but yes, explicitly setting the height solve the problem, Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason, i set  android:weightSum property.
The following is the my layout.xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="2" >


 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/show_text_ricerca_ingredienti"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/show_text_ricerca_ingredienti"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

 <com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView
    android:id="@+id/hlistviewIngredienti"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

  <TextView
       android:id="@+id/show_text_ricerca_per_categorie"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
       android:text="@string/show_text_ricerca_per_categorie"
       android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

   <com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView
        android:id="@+id/hlistview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>




<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="buttonNext"
        android:text="@string/btn_next"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
```